What does the Israeli law say about cabinet votes on military action?
According to Axios:

On Thursday, Netanyahu will convene the security cabinet. According to Israeli law, the prime minister needs a vote of the cabinet for such a significant military action, which could lead to an all-out war with Iran.

A quick search finds that such votes were held before during this war, e.g. in August:

Israel Security Cabinet Votes to Keep Troops in Gaza’s Philadelphi Corridor
[...] Two ministers didn’t vote in favor. They were Defense Minister Yoav Gallant, who was against the measure, and Itamar Ben Gvir, the national security minister, who abstained. Ben Gvir opted not to vote because Netanyahu proposed some draw down of troops and the national security minister wants no reduction at all, according to an official familiar with the matter. Gallant opposed the proposal because he argued it would delay a truce — rather than force Hamas to accept one more quickly — and potentially cost the lives of more hostages, according to an official close to the minister.
The vote was also put to the security cabinet without warning, the official said.

What exactly is this law and what does it say about who can trigger such a vote, and what is needed for a vote to pass in the security cabinet? Clearly not unanimity, given the previous quote. But can e.g. the vote still pass if the PM opposes, for instance?

To get some context, it would be nice to also know what the cabinet consists of and who appoints it under what criteria.  I also assume this is the regular cabinet, not the wartime organization that was put together to include opposition figures right after 10/7.

@ItalianPhilosopher: that one was disbanded in the summer.

I think it should be in the Knesset Rules of Procedure, in the part about the committees, but I can't locate it there

I’m voting to close this question because it belongs to https://law.stackexchange.com/

@Greendrake: laws about the functioning of government are also on topic here. There are a bazillion answers here that quote the US constitution or some electoral law, etc.
